# Как сделать Parental Gate?

Tags: ios

Недавно эппл реджектнул мой апликейшен (игру для детей) на основании того что я использую рекламу Гугла адмоб которая ведет за пределы моей проги, а для этого у меня должен быть парентал гейт. Я нашел пару ресурсов но в коде я не разбираюсь.. Нет ли каких нибудь даже платных ресурсов которые могут даже кретинам установить парентал гейт в свой аппликейшен?

Comment: пробовали на гитхабе искать? вот вам 10 готовых решений https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=parental+gate

Comment: Спасибо громадное! Дело в том что я установить то я установил, например вот этот PMParentalGate - но вот как его в коде именно "вызвать" так чтобы он появлялся когда на in-app purchase тыкаешь или на рекламный банер нажимаешь - тут я пас. Хоть документация какая нибудь была в каком именно файле и где менять что бы заработало, но я так понимаю кодеры это и так знают, поэтому непосвященному в это дело - очень трудно сориентироваться..

Comment: Подождите день другой, может кто-то созреет для вас это написать, хотя, честно говоря сомневаюсь. Тут больше принято отвечать на вопросы, чем писать весь код за кого то.

Comment: Не проблема, не так важно уже ) Я убрал категорию Кидс из своего апликейшена, так что и ПГ теперь не нужен )